# Creating links on another page using a PHP form?

Tags: php, forms

I have a sytem, in PHP. The user will enter some details and those details will be passed on to the next, a page that has 4 empty hyperlinks on it. I was wondering if there was a way to generate the name of the button and the URL it goes to at the same time?

```
<?php 
$company = $_POST["company"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$colour = $_POST["colour"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$video = $_POST["maps"];
?>

<form method="post" action="generate.php"><br>
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="slogan" placeholder="Slogan" /><br>
<input class="color {required:false}" name="colour" placeholder="Company Colour"><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br>
<input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Full Website - Include http://" /><br>
<input type="text" name="maps" placeholder="Google Maps URL" />
<input type="submit" value="Generate QuickLinks"/>
</form>
```

The code above is my form and the code below is what's generated. Please note that every time this form is submitted, a new folder is created and the files from a 'Template' folder are copied over to the new folder. Below is the outcome.

```
<?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 ?>


 <?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php";
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "<div id='logo'>
          <h1 style='color:#$_POST[colour]'>$_POST[company]</h1>
          <h2>$_POST[slogan]</h2>
          </div>

<ul>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='tel:$_POST[phone]'>Phone Us</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='mailto:$_POST[email]'>Email Us</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='$_POST[website]'>View Full Website</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='$_POST[maps]'>Find Us</a></li>
</ul>

 \n";
```

It would be brilliant for me and for the program in general if the user (who's submitting the form could just create the buttons themselves,using a form) I was thinking of keeping '$company, $phone and $email) and then the rest would just be empty links and empty values that the user would fill in, but my form currently doesn't/can't do this. Appreciate it.

Comment: Please give us some code examples. It's difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: Button?  I think you need to figure out your terminology first and foremost... what you're describing makes no sense.

Comment: I've read it like 5 times, but I still can't understand your question. Can you describe it in steps? For example (this is what i understand of your question so far ;)): 1) user filles in form (company name, tel,..), 2) user get's redirected to other page after submit, 3) links are generated based on the post data..

Comment: The user, fills out the form about their company. At the moment the form is very limited, you can't add fields (links) or change what the button on the other end displays. It might help if I told you that this project is a back-end one, and will be used by a company to generate web-pages quickly.